# Changing kafka zookeeper.connect by adding chroot

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Before we haven't set up a chroot for zookeeper, all kafka config are in root folder. So we want to add chroot for the original zookeeper.connect config, then restart the cluster.
I'm wondering what the impact will be.
Will the earlier data get lost? Or some how the data is stored and migrated?

Comment: You'll have to migrate the Zookeeper data yourself. Otherwise, yes, it'll be "lost" on the new config setup